# Is my RAM 2667Mhz or 3200Mhz?

Tags: memory, dell-precision

Is my RAM speed 2666 or 3200 MHz?

From my research 3200MHz runs at `1.2V`, as per my voltage below, and 2667Mhz runs at a higher voltage of about `1.35V`. I looked up the datasheet of the mikron `8ATF1G64HZ-2G6J1` chip, and it says 3200Mhz. However below it says the speed is 2667Mhz. My research also says that windows often miscorrectly reports the speed. So I am no tsure. I have a `Dell Precision 7530 Laptop` that I am trying to upgrade the RAM, and would like to match the speed (before I upgrade the OS to Linux, which may use the full speed). Is windows reporting 2667Mhz because its configured to that?

When I run `wmic memorychip get` from the windows cmd I get the following:

```
Attributes  BankLabel  Capacity    Caption                  ConfiguredClockSpeed  ConfiguredVoltage  CreationClassName     DataWidth  Description              DeviceLocator  FormFactor  HotSwappable  InstallDate  InterleaveDataDepth  InterleavePosition  Manufacturer  MaxVoltage  MemoryType  MinVoltage  Model  Name                     OtherIdentifyingInfo  PartNumber        PositionInRow  PoweredOn  Removable  Replaceable  SerialNumber  SKU  SMBIOSMemoryType  Speed  Status  Tag                TotalWidth  TypeDetail  Version
1                      8589934592  Physikalischer Speicher  2667                  1200               Win32_PhysicalMemory  64         Physikalischer Speicher  DIMM B         12                                     2                    1                   802C0000802C  1200        0           1200               Physikalischer Speicher                        8ATF1G64HZ-2G6J1  1                                                 1F777EF3           26                2667           Physical Memory 0  64          128
1                      8589934592  Physikalischer Speicher  2667                  1200               Win32_PhysicalMemory  64         Physikalischer Speicher  DIMM D         12                                     2                    2                   802C0000802C  1200        0           1200               Physikalischer Speicher                        8ATF1G64HZ-2G6J1  1                                                 1F777F40           26                2667           Physical Memory 2  64          128
```

There seems to be conflicting clues (voltage vs clock speed) of what the RAM hardware speed actually is. So do I buy 2667Mhz or 3200Mhz RAM?

Also strangely enough the 3200MHz memory is cheaper, should I just buy the 3200Mhz and stick it in, and it will run slower at 2666Mhz?

Comment: What memory frequncies does Dell indicate the laptop supports? Based on the information provided, it appears, that the answer to that question is 2667 Mhz.

Comment: Dell says [2400MHz / 2666MHz / 2933MHz](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/it-it/precision-15-7530-laptop/precision_7530_setup_specifications/memory?guid=guid-c8a070cc-7772-48fd-bddc-84b148afe28e&lang=en-us), but [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/dell/precision-7530) says 3200 is compatible

Comment: Even if were to support 3200 MHz that would be an overclock frequency.  Your system likely natively supports 2400 Mhz, 2666 MHz, and 2933 Mhz.

Comment: Related: [RAM compatibility](https://superuser.com/a/1670045/194694)

Comment: thanks @gronostaj, your link says "However if you can get the higher frequency module cheaper (wonders of supply and demand!) consider getting it." so then I will go for the 3200MHz

Comment: Only get the higher frequency if the clock rating is the same value or lower, else it will be slower.